# how to make a solaris system environment same as another

Tags: operating-system, solaris, sunos

I have a real host and an vm. they are both solaris system

```
sjcux-c7build01# uname -a
SunOS sjcux-c7build01 5.8 Generic_Virtual sun4v sparc sun4v
```

The real host has been used for years.The vm is new created.For maintenance，we want to use vm instead of real host in future.I need to install all the packages and let the vm can do gnu make like the old host.

How to list all the packages the real host has installed?
pkginfo just shows what's bundled with Solaris.

I noticed that directory /usr/local/lib in vm is empty,And In real host ,it has many .so file in it.
There must be many other difference. How to find out them? How to list the packages I need to install?

For example.on the vm ,I can't use git.

```
ldd git
        libiconv.so.2 =>         /tools/sw/opt/SunOS/5.8/git/git-2.23.0/lib/libz.so/lib/libiconv.so.2  - Not a directory
        libintl.so.8 =>  /tools/sw/opt/SunOS/5.8/git/git-2.23.0/lib/libz.so/lib/libintl.so.8  - Not a directory
```

So libiconv need to be installed.

I want to make the vm same as the real host, what need I to do? Who can give me some guide~
It is unrealistic to find one by one according to the .so files.

Comment: Hopefully the person(s) respnsible for building the original were familiar with [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) so you could duplicate that system.  If the people who built and maintained that original system didn't do their job and properly document how to duplicate the system, you really can't create a system that's guaranteed to be a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, in case of Solaris you have instruments to make a snapshot of current OS and use it for creation of new machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to create flash archive of your old machine and install from this archive:

- create repository where to store the archive
- create flash archive of the system
- check the archive
- export via NFS the flash archive store
- on new machine boot from CD, choose installation media select NFS

For more detailed instruction you can check [this article](http://unixswing.blogspot.com/2018/10/install-solaris-from-flash-archive.html) in my blog

After creation of new machine you should take care of changing IP address or unconfigure and configure it from scratch (in sense of network and authentication services) it because two machines will have the same IP.